# Add a collection to a view model List

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a view model like

```
    public class MemberCommunicationType
    {
        public long person_id { get; set; }
        public int comm_id { get; set; }
        public someclass cls{ get; set; }
    }

    public class GetMemberColl
    {
        public MemberCommunicationType[] memberCommunication{ get; set; }
    }
```

and I have a query to database like

```
var query = from p in data.GetMember 
           where (p.Client == client && p.Person_id == pid) 
           select p;
```

this query returns two fields: `long person_id`, `int comm_id` which are same in the view model except that the view model has one more field:  `someclass cls`

How can I need add the results returned by the query to my view model?

Output should be a list which contains collection of memberCommunication and a null-valued cls collection for each collection of memberCommunication .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to do something like this:

```
var query = from p in data.GetMember 
            where (p.Client == client && p.Person_id == pid) 
            select new MemberCommunicationType 
                       { person_id = p.person_id, comm_id = p.comm_id}
            ;
var output = new GetMemberColl { memberCommunication = query.ToArray() };
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you a `query` which is of type `IEnumerable<MemberCommunicationType>`.

```
var query = from p in data.GetMember 
            where (p.Client == client && p.Person_id == pid) 
            select new MemberCommunicationType
            {
                person_id = p.Person_id,
                comm_id = p.comm_id,
                cls = null
            };
```

You can then convert it to a `List<T>` with `query.ToList()`.

Comment: Hi- I get this error because I included cls=null, in the query"Unable to create a constant value of type 'Class'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context"